# How to disambiguate overloaded template functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, overloading, variadic-templates

There is a problem with the following code. While 1 part is OK, the problem is with the 2nd part of the `main()`. On compilation, an ambiguous error message is displayed. How can I change the code to resolve the ambiguity?

```
template<typename Arg> void func(Arg arg) 
{  
    arg();
}
template<typename Arg, typename... Args> void func(Arg arg, Args... args) 
{  
    func(args...);
    arg();
}
template<typename Container> void func(Container & c) 
{
    for (typename Container::reverse_iterator i = c.rbegin(); i != c.rend(); ++i ) 
    { 
        (*i)();
    } 
}

void f()
{
    std::cout << "+" ;
}

int main()
{
    //1
    func(f,f,f);

    //2    
    std::vector<std::function<void()> > v{f,f};
    func(v);
}
```

Link to code: http://cpp.sh/3wxrc

Comment: Look like you need some SFINAE. Define a type traits `is_container` then add an `enable_if<!is_container<Arg>>` in your `1)` declaration

Comment: I suppose it will work, but will look a bit cumbersome...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I change the code to resolve the ambiguity?

Maybe using template-template ?

```
template <template <typename ...> class Cont, typename ... Ts>
void func (Cont<Ts...> & c) 
{
    for (typename Cont<Ts...>::reverse_iterator i = c.rbegin(); i != c.rend(); ++i ) 
    { 
        (*i)();
    } 
}
```

Deleting the `func()` `Container` based version, obviously.

Simply defining a template parameter `Container`, doen't make it different from a generic `Arg` template parameter.

I know that you use `typename Cont<Ts...>::reverse_iterator` inside the function. But the compiler has to choose the right overloading according the function signature, not according the body of the functions.

Using a `Cont<Ts...>` parameter, you have something more specialized.

Comment: You still do not check that `typename Cont<Ts...>::reverse_iterator i = c.rbegin();` is valid. This prevents using `func` with templated functors as input. If this becomes necessary at any point, we are back at SFINAE as Martin Morterol suggested.

Comment: @generic_opto_guy - You're right, but seems to me that the problem (and the OP preparation) is more basic. I don't know if is the case to introduce SFINAE where the point is the less or more specialization.

Answer (score 2):

If you have C++17 there is `std::enable_if_t` which can be used with `std::is_invocable_v` (this requiries C++17) :

```cpp
template<typename Arg>
std::enable_if_t<std::is_invocable_v<Arg>>
func(Arg arg) 
{  
    arg();
}
```

https://wandbox.org/permlink/E2PoQdMv1pwXdMgO

Answer (score 1):

I would first split (variadic) iteration, from singular job:

```
// func overloads with one parameter.

template <typename ...Ts>
void funcs(Ts&&... args) 
{
    const int dummy[] = {(func(std::forward<Ts>(args)), 0)..., 0};
    static_cast<void>(dummy); // Avoid warning for unused variable

    // Or in C++17:
    // (func(std::forward<Ts>(args)), ...);
}
```

Then for your methods with only one argument, there are ambiguous for any lvalue reference, as signatures are:

```
template<typename Arg> void func(Arg arg);
template<typename Container> void func(Container & c);
```

You might use SFINAE to differentiate them:

```
template<typename Arg>
auto func(Arg arg)
-> decltype(arg(), void())
{  
    arg();
}

template<typename Container>
auto func(Container& c)
-> decltype(c.rbegin() != c.rend(), (*c.rbegin())(), void())
{
    for (auto it = c.rbegin(); it != c.rend(); ++it) 
    { 
        (*it)();
    } 
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/9LOEyE)

Comment: Good solution! At line `#2` you probably meant a call to `funcs()` too.

Comment: @Qwertypal: Demo fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that it couldn't deduce which `func` to call` the first one or the third. This is how you can make it work without changing your hierarchy of function overloadings or do as it answered in last comment

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<algorithm>
#include<functional>
template<typename Arg> 
void func(Arg* arg) 
{  
    arg();
}
template<typename Arg, typename... Args> 
void func(Arg arg, Args... args) 
{  
    func(args...);
    arg();
}
template<typename Container> 
void func(Container&& c) 
{
    for (typename Container::reverse_iterator i = c.rbegin(); i != c.rend(); ++i ) 
    { 
        (*i)();
    } 
    //OR Which is bettere to use
    /*for(auto && e : c){
        e();
    }*/
}

void f()
{
    std::cout << "+" ;
}

int main()
{
    //1
    func(f,f,f);

    //2    
    std::vector<std::function<void()> > v{f,f};
    func(std::move(v));
}
```